# For loop only way to copy array content to another array?

Tags: vba

I have some code that has heavy use of arrays. It all works but there are many for loops where I iterate and copy contents from several arrays to a new array with more dimensions to fit all content.

As I understand it, there is no way to do this without a for loop (to copy array content to another array). Is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

There is the method Array.Copy(arSource,arTarget,length). But it does not work with more dimensions arrays. The new one is that jagged arrays()arrays of arrays are more perfomant than 2D ARRAYS,if you move along the vectors.

Comment: Are you refering to the method Array.Copy method in the second sentence?

Comment: To use Array.Copy(....) you must have 1D arrays.  You told us that you utilize more dimensional arrays, so you could not utilize it. But if you change the structure of the array into jagged array you  improve the performance of the software and also you can utilize Array.Copy(...)  But I read somewhere that the jagged array improve his performance only if you move along the vector. Because if you move between the columns you have no benefits, or worst you could have relative slower code.  Give a look at this link:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973839.aspx

Comment: The OP is tagged [vba] aren't Array.Copy and jagged arrays both [.net]?